# How to get 24:XX time from datetime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

Is there a DateTime Format that allows representation of the 24-hour clock to roll over where 24:XX is valid time?

For example

```
const secondsToTimeOfDay = (totalSeconds: number): string => {
  return new Date(totalSeconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
};

var x = secondsToTimeOfDay(86399)
console.log(x)
```

Returns

```
23:59:59
```

But when seconds are greater than 86400 (The number of seconds in one day) it starts on the next day?

Example

```
var x = secondsToTimeOfDay(87000)
console.log(x)
```

Returns

```
00:10:00
```

Is there a **date format** that will return in a 24:xx format?

Example (I know this works but I want to know if it can be done using some kind of built-in Date Object)

```
const SomeNewFunction = (totalSeconds: number): string => {
  var duration = 1000*totalSeconds
  var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)));

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}    

var x = SomeNewFunction(87000)
var y = SomeNewFunction(97000)
console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

Returns

```
24:10:00
26:56:40
```

Where the SomeNewFuntion uses some kind of **DateTimeObject** rather than math?

Comment: What's the context? Why do you want that?

Comment: That wouldn't be a valid time. You may need to convert it as a string for display.

Comment: Hours over 24 aren't *times* anymore, they're *durations*. `Date` related functionality doesn't work for durations. Javascript doesn't have any classes for handling durations built in.

Comment: There are instances where that is valid time - for eg in scheduling arrival times. I just wanted to know if there is a built-in Object that allows for the parsing and representation of that Time Format.

Comment: GTFS and Transmodel. Especially a schedule is delayed: For example, some trains run at 12:30AM, but are listed for the previous days service (for some reason - either its a delayed service or a sweeper service), and that running time is stored as 24:30 in the GTFS specification.

Comment: If you want to use 24 instead of 00 for midnight you can do that with [*Intl.DateTimeFormat#format*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) using the option `hourCylce: 24` or `hc-24` in the language tag, e.g. `new Date(2020,0,1,0).toLocaleString('en', {hourCycle:'h24'});` or `new Date(2020,0,1,0).toLocaleString('en-u-hc-h24');` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` object represents a single instant in the history of the world, both date and time. While you can ignore the date part in display, it is always there - `new Date(300000)` doesn't represent "00:05:00 on any day", it represents "00:05:00 *on January 1st 1970, according to UTC*".

Since January 1st 1970 didn't have a 25th and 26th hour, the format you're asking for wouldn't make sense. Put a different way, "Feb 2nd 02:00" and "Feb 1st 26:00" are the same instant in time, but (if I understand your problem correctly) you want to be able to represent them distinctly.

There are time-related objects where "the 26th hour" would make sense:

- A "duration", representing an absolute amount of time, independent of when it happens.
- An "interval", representing the span of time between two specific instants.
- A "time of day", in certain specialised cases, where you want to consider the "day" to last more than 24 hours for planning purposes.

JavaScript doesn't currently have any of those built-in, although there are libraries that do, and [a proposal for adding them natively](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html).

It's likely that most "time of day" implementations would not allow for more than 24 hours in the day, but you could represent it using a "duration" or "interval". The end result might look something like this:

```js
var timetableEntry = {
    "date": Temporal.PlainDate.from({year: 2006, month: 8, day: 24}),
    "startOffsetFromMidnight": Temporal.Duration.from({ hours: 23, minutes: 30 }),
    "endOffsetFromMidnight": Temporal.Duration.from({ hours: 26, minutes: 30 })
}

var journeyDuration = timetableEntry.endOffsetFromMidnight.subtract( timetableEntry.startOffsetFromMidnight );
var startDateTime = timetableEntry.date.add( timetableEntry.startOffsetFromMidnight );
var endDateTime = timetableEntry.date.add( timetableEntry.endOffsetFromMidnight);
```